# Save Result As At

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tempo

How can I save the output result of the at command to a TXT file as a logger?

What I tried was...

> echo "command" | at now + 1 hour>file.txt

more unfortunately he did not save the result.

I would just like to save the results that the at command produces after finishing the output.

result that it will generate after completed

warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh                           job 141 at Sat Jul 29 23:44:00 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you just need to redirect the output to the file by adding

```
`echo "command" | at now + 1 hour>file.txt 2>&1`
```

or

```
`echo "command" | at now + 1 hour>&file.txt`
```

- 0 is stdin
- 1 is stdout
- 2 is stderr

Comment: manage to save now, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

`at` outputs to stderr, you have to do `echo "command" | at now + 1 hour 2>file.txt`.